# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver when connecting to azure database

Tags: azure-sql-database, sqlexception

im using an azure database and I added all necessary JAR files to my library. Here is my code, im not sure why it is unable to connect. Please advise.

```
 String connectionUrl =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://bcs430-final-project.database.windows.net:1433;"
                        + "database=OASIS ASSISTANT;"
                        + "user=farmingdale@bcs430-final-project;"
                        + "password=bcs430w!;"
                        + "encrypt=true;"
                        + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
                        + "loginTimeout=30;";




     String insertSql = "select * from dbo.BCS102 where crse = bcs102 ";

        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                PreparedStatement prepsInsertProduct = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);) {

            prepsInsertProduct.execute();
            // Retrieve the generated key from the insert.
            resultSet = prepsInsertProduct.getGeneratedKeys();

            // Print the ID of the inserted row.
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("Generated: " + resultSet.getString(1));
            }
        }
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here is the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://bcs430-final-project.database.windows.net:1433;database=OASIS ASSISTANT;user=farmingdale@bcs430-final-project;password=bcs430w!;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at SeniorProject.main(SeniorProject.java:35)
```

Comment: Hi ,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you didn't install suitable  the drive for JDBC.

Please check the if you have add the dependency. Add the Microsoft **JDBC Driver for SQL Server** to your project's dependencies using the following code.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details, you can reference this document [Quickstart: Use Java to connect to and query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-java).You can follow this tutorial and avoid the error.

In addition, you want to connect to your Azure SQL database with AD authentication, you connection string should like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433;database=Mydatabase;user={your_username_here};password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword
```

You can get the AD connection string on Portal:

[image]

Hope this helps.